# Getting the same email almost every time I open macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, email, unix

Almost every time I open Terminal on **macOS** I find new mail sent somewhat (10 identical emails, or sometimes more). I believe something I did or installed caused this, but I couldn't figure out what is it?

Does anybody know how to stop this?

```
From me@Me-MacBook.local  Tue Feb 12 23:03:01 2019
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@Me-MacBook.local
From: me@Me-MacBook.local (Cron Daemon)
To: me@Me-MacBook.local
Subject: Cron <me@Me-MacBook> /Users/me/Library/triliterally.oy/triliterally.oy cr
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=me>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=me>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/me>
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 23:03:00 +0200 (EET)

/bin/sh: /Users/me/Library/triliterally.oy/triliterally.oy: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem like these are cron generated error notifications. Have you added something to your crontab perhaps? Or some application named along the lines of triliterally that may have added a cron entry?

Check your crontab with `crontab -l`. If you see that there is an entry that seems to line up... and you don't know what it is, use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab and just commment out that line with a leading "#". Save it and then see if the email stops.

If it does not... and it does actually happen every time you open a terminal... check to see what you have in your .bash_profile or .bashrc files looking to see if there are relevant entries there.

Comment: Yes, i got the following entry in crontab: `3 * * * * /Users/me/Library/triliterally.oy/triliterally.oy cr`. I commented it, but is it safe to delete the entry?

Comment: Probably safe to remove as the cron entry failed as it could not find the file... but I would be curious to find out what it is. If the directory does not exist at all (under Library) then it may be something that you had installed and then uninstalled that did not clean up after itself.

Comment: In case you are not familiar with cron/crontab - basically this is a scheduled task. It is trying to run that task at the described time interval. So if you comment it out and/or delete, you are just removing the task, not anything else. Now IF this was performing a necessary task, you would no longer have that automated.

Comment: OK, I see. the directory doesn't exist..anyway will make a snapshot just-in-case and delete...many thanks.